# bootstrap navbar in div with width: 40% for ipad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple map site with a sidebar that I can toggle on and off. All works fine on Pc and telephone, but I can't get the responsive navbar functionality to work on a tablet.

Here is the css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.container-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.map{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: inherit;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 10005;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
/*
 * iPad - nav list not complete
 */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
  .sidebar {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
/*
 * Phone - works
 */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

and the html:

```
<!-- form container -->
<div class="container sidebar" id="form-container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse sidebar-header" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form-container-navbar"  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a id="form-container-title" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Form</a>
        </div><!-- /navbar-header -->

        <div id="form-container-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
             <li><a href="#">Open</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Maybe</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Whatever</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
             <li><a id="close-form" href="#">Close</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- container -->
  </nav><!-- navbar -->

  <form role="form" id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="species">Species</label>
      <input id="species" class="form-control" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="risk">Risk</label>

<!-- etc, etc -->
```

On a pc I get a horizontal menu that extends beyond the 'sidebar'. This is fine.
On a phone I get the collapsed menu that I can toggle - also fine.
But on an iPad I get a horizontal menu that works, but I can't see the text that is beyond the width of the .sidebar. Unhelpful.

Ideally I'd get the collapsed menu I can toggle, or a horizontal menu I can see!

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Mini

Comment: Your navigation is inside the sidebar instead of at the top of the page. is this intentional?

Comment: Yes. I have one at the top that works fine, but this is a different one specific to #form-container

Comment: I can't help right now because it's Mother's day, but see if this will help: http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/

Comment: Thanks - looks like a good plugin, but I'd like to do this with just Bootstraps CSS - has to be possible :)

Comment: it's hard to fully understand what you're doing without all the code. For instance, you're sidebar is hidden, so I have to manually unhide it to even see it. How is the user going to see it? Also, you have a log of nav links in the sidebar - too many to even fit. Is this intentional as well?

Comment: Working demo here: https://treemapp.se/dev/fiddles/ol/bootstrap-4.html. The number of nav links is deliberate so I can test how it works on e.g. iPad/telephone. On an iPad I'd like it to toggle those links into a button, like it does on the 'phone', or show them on the full width navbar. On iPad I can't get it to do either at the moment, just get my nav links truncated at the width of the side panel

Comment: Your design is *really* confusing. Once I actually realized I was in the sidebar I had no way to get back out. I believe having the menu in the sidebar is causing the issue. I think you need to rethink your design. Look into bootstraps `hidden` and `visible` classes, I think they may help you. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: The design is probably more apparent when the map is there (I removed it from the demo for speed/testing) Thanks for the link - it could be the way forward.